# Automated testing of a system of several connected computers

Tags: system-testing, test-architecture

I work in a lab containing a system of computers and simulators interacting with each other in order to recreate a complete and accurate boat simulation.

The software used on these machines receives an update from our development team every 3 or 4 months and we run the software through a big batch of tests to make sure it works properly (~100+ tests each time)

Around 80% of these tests can be easily automated but we have no means to do that yet.

My project is to come up with an architecture for a system allowing us to run automated tests on our computers (several at once). In order to begin, I'm looking to get an idea of the state of the art in the domain of systems set up to run automated tests.

I have a vague idea of what I'm looking for: examples and ideas of computers set up on a network with all the SUT's (System Under Test) and how they interact.

Would you have any sources of information, documents and papers I could look into in order to get an idea of what already exists?

Thank you very much and sorry for the imprecision of what I'm asking, I'm only just starting, trying to figure things out.

Comment: So you want to automate deployment of the software to the network of computers? Is a simulator a separate hardware or a software on the computer? How software from development team gets deployed there?

Comment: Please add some details on what kind of tests you are running - unit, integrated or UI

Comment: Software is already deployed

Simulators are all on virtual machines on a server

We then have several machines communicating with these simulators in order to recreate the boat in operational conditions.

The tests I have to run are on the simulators and the machines connecting to them.

The tests are only UI (clicking on buttons and seeing how everything reacts)

Comment: You might look into using a continuous integration system like Jenkins. CI systems have a concept of "build agents" where you can have tasks (e.g. tests) run on different machines. The interaction piece would be interesting to figure out but it might be possible. Equally hand-wavey, but hope it's helpful.

Comment: I'd suggest editing your question title to be more descriptive. Something like "automated testing of a system of several connected computers". Currently it's rather generic and sounds like an opinion-based question, which I don't think it is.

Comment: "80% can be easily automated".  That's what folks think.  Then they discover selenium, intermittent failures, flakey tests, data issues, environment issues, etc.  every place I've worked at has them and each one has thought it was specific to them

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below tool which has an excellent concept of Agents for multiple machine and multiple locations.

[https://testproject.io/](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xq8zFDb2CAw)

You can run your same script on multiple browsers.
You can run your script on multiple machines in the same network and remote places.
You can run your script on a different machine with different browsers and many more.

Please refer below video for more details.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xq8zFDb2CAw

It is a free tool and runs the selenium script behind the picture. Also, it is capable to generate selenium web driver code in Java and other languages that you can use in your existing code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to execute automated scripts on multiple machines then Selenium Grid allows to run tests in parallel mode on different machines and different browsers available on that machines. Selenium grid working is based on Master Slave architecture.
Please refer this article for Setnium GRID SETP and sample execution.
http://mundrisoft.com/tech-bytes/wp-admin/post.php?post=6196&action=edit

Answer (score 0):

Are the connected computers all doing the same thing or are they performing specific activities?  If the latter, your aim may be to test at each computer to computer interface, however it is implemented: api, browser, etc.

If they (or more than one of them) are running browsers then @sachin's suggestion to look into selenium grid is a good one.